# 550-Please deliver mail to the address specified in the MX records for this 550 domain

Tags: email, dns, php, smtp, iis-7

I have a PHP script which emails the results of a form to a specified address.  Previously it was working fine but now it's not sending email anymore.  When I check the error log, I see this error:

> [22-Jan-2015 13:36:18 America/Tegucigalpa] PHP Warning:  mail(): SMTP
>   server response: 550-Please deliver mail to the address specified in
>   the MX records for this 550 domain. in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sendticket.php on line 32

Line 32:

```
mail($to, $subject, $text);
```

What is causing this, and what do I need to change to fix it?